# Malformed eMail Date Header Field with Address Specification

Tags: email, smtp, mbox, rfc5322

When parsing a collection of MBox files, I came across a surprising number of Date header fields of the form:

`"Date:" date-time "<" addr-spec ">"`

Reading the available RFCs I find no matching syntax. The valid form appears to be:

`"Date:" date-time [CFWS]`

CFWS represents comments plus folding whitespace as described in Section 3.3 (Date and Time Specification) of [RFC5322](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322).

Reading [Proper Mail Date Header Formatting](https://jrklein.com/2014/11/18/proper-mail-date-header-formatting-rfc-4021-rfc-2822-rfc-822-and-analysis-of-132k-date-headers/) where the author analyses 132k date headers, yet the form above never shows in the linked dataset.

Is this an MBox artefact, IMF attribute, or corruption from a mail agent and/or mail relay?

The Internet Message Format has been evolving since the 1980s, it's a bit of a mess and has been interpreted a number of ways à la HTTP.  I'm leaning toward this being a vendor-specific modification that results in a malformed Date header field? IDK.

**Example MBox**

```
From ???@???
From: from@mail.com
To: to@mail.com
Date: Sat, 02 Feb 2002 00:55:01 +0000 <name@mail.com>
Subject: Email One

This is email 1.
```

**Specifications**

- [RFC 5322](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322)
- [RFC 2822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822)
- [RFC 822](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc822)
- [RFC 4021](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4021)
- [MBox Format](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000383.shtml)
- [MBOXO Format](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000384.shtml)
- [MBOXRD Format](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000385.shtml)
- [MBOXCL Format](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000386.shtml)
- [MBOXCL2 Format](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000387.shtml)
- [RFC 5321](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321)
- [RFC 2821](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2821)

Comment: I have never seen this particular form of corruption in my 25+ years of staring at email messages. Probably very specific to a particular piece of software, perhaps something you ran locally?

Comment: Same. I've never seen this in my 25+ years of writing MIME & mbox parsers.